# How to calculate "order" in a Apriori Hashing Technique

Tags: hash, data-mining, mining

I am new to Data Mining and is studying Apriory Algo (Hashing Technique to be specific). The explanation is fine but the example shows a `hash function h(x, y)= ((order of x)*10 + (order of y)) mod 7`.

Can anybody tell what is this order in here? I am attaching the snapshots of the same:

[image]

Referred Table:

[image]

Comment: Can you add your code, if you have some.

Comment: No there is no code, just this theoretical explanation is available in most of the places.

Answer (score 1):

Got it, it was nothing just the sequence number of the entities.

Answer (score 0):

I too could not understand the term order. The term sequence number in the answer above is helpful, but i decided to post an example of how the bucket address is calculated so that future visitors can get complete understanding.

Here is how **{I2, I4}** is placed in bucket address **3**:

order of x i.e. order of I2 is 2
order of y i.e. order of I4 is 4

h(x, y) = ( (order of x ) * 10 + ( order of y ) ) mod 7
h(I2, I4) = ( 2 * 10 + 4 ) mod 7
h(I2, I4) = ( 20 + 4 ) mod 7
h(I2, I4) = ( 24 ) mod 7 = 3